# Creating ASP.NET web application with multiple skins?

Tags: asp.net, css, themes, skinning

I'm currently in the process of developing an ASP.NET WebForms application that will have multiple skins.  The way I'm thinking of approaching this is to have each skin in a completely separate folder, which will contain all images and CSS, and the CSS will reference images accordingly.

The folder structure would be something like this:

- /Default.aspx
- /Skins/Master.css
- /Skins1/Skin1/Skin1.css
- /Skins1/Skin1/Images/ ...
- /Skins1/Skin1/Skin2.css
- /Skins1/Skin2/Images/ ...
- /Skins1/Skin1/Skin3.css
- /Skins1/Skin3/Images/ ...

So, for example, we might have:

```
<div id="foo-logo"></div>
<a href="/bar/"><div id="bar-logo"></div></a>
```

And then in the CSS:

```
#top-logo { height: 100px; width:200px; background:url(images/foo-logo.jpg); }
#bar-logo { height: 50px;  width:100px; background:url(images/bar-logo.jpg); }
```

My logic behind this is to avoid having references to the skin folder in-line with the code, like this:

```
<img src="/skins/<%=Settings.CurrentSkin%>/images/foo-logo.jpg" />
<a href="/bar/"><img src="/skins/<%=Settings.CurrentSkin%>/images/bar-logo.jpg" /></a>
```

This way, the HTML will remain clean and be completely independent, and it will be possible to completely change the skin simply by referencing a different CSS file and remove the need to update image tags.

The main downsides of this that I can think of are:

- Image dimensions on the containing element will need to be specifically specified in CSS as they will be implemented as CSS background-images
- Web application may not degrade as well if important brand elements such as the logo are only visible with CSS

Is there anything else I should be aware of when using this method and/or is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: How is the appropriate skin chosen? Is it a user-specific setting, or something that is automatically selected based on some other condition?

Comment: The web application is going to have multiple URLs, and the skin will be selected based on the URL that is being used to accessed it.

Answer (score 1):

WebForms has support for Themes and Skinning which does a lot of what you seem to want to  do here, some helpful articles are

[Ode to Code](http://www.odetocode.com/articles/423.aspx),
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx)

What skinning basically allows you to do is define seperate stylesheets and control skins. The folder structure you have would be look like

App_Themes/Skin1

App_Themes/Skin2

App_Themes/Skin3

...

You can then use asp:Image controls that point to distinct image urls for each skin ID (or you can do it via CSS).